# "The file 'defaultAction' could not be found."

Tags: eclipse

When I try to start a second instance of eclipse, I get this error:

> "The file 'defaultAction' could not be found."

Any ideas?

Here is my .ini file:

```
-vm
C:/tools/java/jdk1.7.51/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.openFile
defaultAction
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can put "`defaultAction`" at the start of a line in your `eclipse.ini`.

The [eclipse.ini options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) do include `--launcher.defaultAction <option> (Executable)` (introduced in [issue 314953](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314953)), but not `defaultAction` alone.

So remove the lines:

```
--launcher.openFile
defaultAction
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how that got off.